# How to fix firebug errors while loading jquery.dataTables.min.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js, datatables

I had used the below to scripts to include d3 and jQuery plugins.

```
a)<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

I'm facing this error in the console of firebug.

```
 1)TypeError: e[j] is undefined

    ...post);for(a=0;a<n.length;a++){j=n[a][0];f=e[j].aDataSort;b=0;for(c=f.length;b<c;...

    jquery.....min.js (line 64, col 203)
```

How can I fix this issue.Can anyone please help me out ...

--> My code looks like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
  <head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.11.2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/ellipse.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

<div>
<form action="/home/divya/html_docs/click.html" method="post" id="form1">
Client_ip :<input type="text" id ="ip" name="client_ip" style="width: 600px;"/>
<div id="subDiv">
<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</div></br>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
</table>

 <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#ip").val('');

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
} );


  var tabulate = function (data,columns) {
var svg = d3.select('#ip').append("svg")
  var table = d3.select('#example')
    var thead = table.append('thead')
    var tbody = table.append('tbody')

    thead.append('tr')
      .selectAll('th')
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
      .append('th')
        .text(function (d) { return d })

    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
      .append('tr')

    var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function (column) {
                return { column: column, value: row[column] }
          })
      })
      .enter()
    .append('td')
   .text(function (d) { return d.value })
   .append("input")
   .attr("id","change")
   .attr("type", "checkbox")
   .style("float","left")
.on("click", function(d,i) { 
var arr = [];
if (this.checked) {

   this.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
$('#ip').val(function( index, val ) {
 arr = val.trim().length > 1 ? val.split(',') : []; //split textbox value in to array
arr.push(d.value); //add id to array
return arr.join(','); 
});

  } else if (this.checked == false) {
      this.removeAttribute("checked");
$('#ip').val(function( index, val ) {
arr.splice(index, d.value);
});
  }

});

  return table;
}


d3.csv('http://localhost:3000/getcsv',function (data) {
    var columns = ['client_ip']
  tabulate(data,columns)
});
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm unable  to include  this plugin in my html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

I'm facing the following error in firebug,

```
TypeError: e[j] is undefined

...post);for(a=0;a<n.length;a++){j=n[a][0];f=e[j].aDataSort;b=0;for(c=f.length;b<c;...

    jquery.....min.js (line 64, col 203)
```

Due to this error,I'm unable to include pagination in my html page.It works like this,http://plnkr.co/edit/PDsWf6QpCFanXljLqxyg?p=preview.Now ,I want to also add pagination into my html page.Can anyone help me out regarding this issue ...

Comment: These errors typically happen because you are trying to assign an event handler to a DOM element, but the DOM element hasn't been created yet. Either put your JavaScript code inside a `$(function () { ......... })` block or put all of your JavaScript code at the bottom of your HTML file.

Comment: I had edited my code here.Can u please help me out in arranging the code

Comment: Hmm. [Works here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PDsWf6QpCFanXljLqxyg?p=preview) - I don't get any errors as above, just some errors related to DataTable configuration.

Comment: Actually I had included pagination plugin over here.But it is unable to load that plugin.In the above link the pagination is missing in that page.

Comment: I'm facing this error: TypeError: e[j] is undefined in firebug while loading , <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

Comment: There was no mention of a pagination plugin in your question. Please edit your question and add the details on this plugin and where you include it in your code.

Comment: And one thing I want to mention over here is that ,if I place an alert box,it is including pagination after clicking ok button of alert box.If I remove alert box,I'm unable to include pagination.Can u please guide me what is the problem over here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to include jquery.dataTables.min.js in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691945/unable-to-include-jquery-datatables-min-js-in-html)